# View optimization with count function in output

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I'm using this following view directly in SQL Server Management Studio. It works fine, but I cannot find out why it's too slow.

I verified disk IO, CPU, and the server has enough RAM.
The inner tables have proper indexes.

Can you help me rewriting/reviewing it in a optimized way?

```
SELECT instances.id, 
       instances.unlisted, 
       instances.unread, 
       instances.folderid, 
       instances.partitionfactor, 
       instances.draftid, 
       instances.targetletterid, 
       instances.targetpendingletterid, 
       instances.flag, 
       instances.comments, 
       instances.viewdate, 
       drafts.attachmentcount                AS [DraftAttachmentCount], 
       drafts.bodyfilecount                  AS [DraftBodyFileCount], 
       drafts.[date], 
       drafts.sendertitle, 
       drafts.[browsetoreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[priority], 
       drafts.[priorityid], 
       drafts.subject, 
       drafts.[toreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[ccreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[security], 
       drafts.[securityid], 
       drafts.[body], 
       destinationSender.[fulltitle]         AS [DestinationSenderTitle], 
       incompleteDrafts.frozenid, 
       incompleteDrafts.frozenaction, 
       ( CASE WHEN Isnull(instances.[notecount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Note' END 
         + CASE 
         WHEN Isnull(instances.[alertcount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Alert' END + 
         CASE 
         WHEN Isnull([categorycount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Category' END ) 
                                             [AttachedObjects], 
       drafts.[guid]                         DraftGuid, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   dbo.myperfixdraftdestinationreceivers 
        WHERE  draftid = drafts.id)          [DraftDestinationReceivers], 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   dbo.myperfixdraftdestinationreceivers 
        WHERE  draftid = drafts.id 
               AND ( receivertype = 4 
                      OR receivertype = 5 )) [ExternalReceivers] 
FROM   myperfixdraftinstances instances 
       LEFT JOIN myperfixdrafts drafts 
              ON ( drafts.[partitionfactor] = instances.[partitionfactor] 
                   AND drafts.[id] = instances.[draftid] ) 
       LEFT JOIN com_staff destinationSender 
              ON ( destinationSender.[id] = drafts.[destinationsenderid] ) 
       LEFT JOIN myperfixincompletesavedrafts incompleteDrafts 
              ON ( instances.id = incompleteDrafts.draftinstanceid ) 

go
```

Comment: You make the claim that the indexes and environment are set up optimally, so there is really little input anyone else can give you.  A simpler query and execution plan would both help.

Comment: Without the query plan we can only guess. But like Gordon said, if you've already properly indexed the table, there's little ideas we can offer.

Comment: if `drafts.id` can have repetitions, then getting the count outside the select clause and keeping them in a temp table could help. Within the select you can access the count from the temp table. You may also index the temp table.

Comment: Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the correlated subquery would be the culprit. Have you tried removing it?

And is there a reason you need to do outer joins? You return a lot of values from the drafts, but only outer join it to the instances. Have you got a lot of instances without drafts?

If so you might improve it by doing inner joins, and then do a "union all" between a query where you look at all instances without drafts and the query above with an inner join on drafts.

My first attempt, keeping the outer joins but removing the correlated subqueries would be:

```
with drafts AS
(
SELECT
       d.[id]
       d.attachmentcount, 
       d.bodyfilecount, 
       d.[date], 
       d.sendertitle, 
       d.[browsetoreceiverlist], 
       d.[priority], 
       d.[priorityid], 
       d.subject, 
       d.[toreceiverlist], 
       d.[ccreceiverlist], 
       d.[security], 
       d.[securityid], 
       d.[body],
       r.[DraftDestinationReceivers],
       r.[ExternalReceivers]
from myperfixdrafts d
left join 
    (SELECT draftid,Count(*) [DraftDestinationReceivers],sum(iif(receivertype in (4,5),1,0)) [ExternalReceivers] from dbo.myperfixdraftdestinationreceivers group by draftid) r
on d.[id]=r.draftid
)
SELECT instances.id, 
       instances.unlisted, 
       instances.unread, 
       instances.folderid, 
       instances.partitionfactor, 
       instances.draftid, 
       instances.targetletterid, 
       instances.targetpendingletterid, 
       instances.flag, 
       instances.comments, 
       instances.viewdate, 
       drafts.attachmentcount                AS [DraftAttachmentCount], 
       drafts.bodyfilecount                  AS [DraftBodyFileCount], 
       drafts.[date], 
       drafts.sendertitle, 
       drafts.[browsetoreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[priority], 
       drafts.[priorityid], 
       drafts.subject, 
       drafts.[toreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[ccreceiverlist], 
       drafts.[security], 
       drafts.[securityid], 
       drafts.[body], 
       destinationSender.[fulltitle]         AS [DestinationSenderTitle], 
       incompleteDrafts.frozenid, 
       incompleteDrafts.frozenaction, 
       ( CASE WHEN Isnull(instances.[notecount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Note' END 
         + CASE 
         WHEN Isnull(instances.[alertcount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Alert' END + 
         CASE 
         WHEN Isnull([categorycount], 0) = 0 THEN '' ELSE 'Category' END ) 
                                             [AttachedObjects], 
       drafts.[guid]                         DraftGuid, 
       drafts.[DraftDestinationReceivers], 
       drafts.[ExternalReceivers] 
FROM   myperfixdraftinstances instances 
       LEFT JOIN  drafts 
              ON ( drafts.[partitionfactor] = instances.[partitionfactor] 
                   AND drafts.[id] = instances.[draftid] ) 
       LEFT JOIN com_staff destinationSender 
              ON ( destinationSender.[id] = drafts.[destinationsenderid] ) 
       LEFT JOIN myperfixincompletesavedrafts incompleteDrafts 
              ON ( instances.id = incompleteDrafts.draftinstanceid )
```